# Set working directory in C code on OSX

Tags: macos, sdl-2

I'm porting some code from a SDL(+mixer)-based C-language PC app, which is surprisingly straightforward. However, I'm a bit stumped about how to load resources.

The original code placed its resources in subdirectories - graphics/, sound/ etc. The code then loads the resources referring to the subdirectory, for instance, `Mix_LoadWAV(sounds/zap.waz)`. Sprites are handled in a similar manner, using fopen("graphics/stars.pcx") and then processing the data.

On the Mac, these fail with a file not found. I assume this is either because the working directory is in the wrong place, or fopen needs complete paths?

If there are any OSX SDL people out there, do you have any pointers on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen()` does not need complete paths. You're probably right that the working directory is not what the app expects (although I wouldn't say it's "wrong" since there's no expectation for the working directory except when a program is launched from the command line, where the user controls it).

The POSIX way to change the working directory is:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int chdir(const char *path);
```

To discover the path of the application bundle, you use Core Foundation's [CFBundle API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFBundleRef/Reference/reference.html). So, something like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>

...
CFURLRef url = CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL(CFBundleGetMainBundle());
char path[PATH_MAX];
if (!CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation(url, true, (UInt8*)path, sizeof(path)) ||
    chdir(path) != 0)
    /* handle error */;
CFRelease(url);
```

Here I've used the path of the Resources directory inside the app bundle (YourApp.app/Contents/Resources). If that's not where your resource files are actually located, you'd use one of the other CFBundle functions.

Comment: Worked like a champ, and retains x-platform compat with an ifdef!